# Combining two int's arrays into one array by order not working

Tags: c#, arrays

i need to combine to arrays into one by number order
the problem is that when one of the array's got all her parts in the array that combine the two,
the iA or iB is bigger than the array length

```
static void Merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] c = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    int iA = 0, iB = 0, iC = 0;
    
    while (iA < a.Length && iB < b.Length)
    {
        if (a[iA] < b[iB])
        {
            c[iC] = a[iA];
            iC++; iA++;
        }
        else if (a[iA] > b[iB])
        {
            c[iC] = b[iB];
            iC++; iB++;
        }
        else
        {
            c[iC] = a[iA];
            iC++; iA++;
            c[iC] = b[iB];
            iC++; iB++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
    }
}
```

Then I execute it

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] b = { 2, 5, 8, 11};
    Merge(a, b);
}
```

this is the output

```
5
8
10
11
0
0
0
0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

please i need to find a solution

Comment: Have you ever checked LINQ's `Concat` method for that?

Comment: The while condition is wrong. Just think of an extreme case where one of the arrays is empty - then the loop will never be entered.

Comment: @SonerGönül ... followed by an `OrderBy` so that the requirement "by number order" is met

Comment: @SonerGönül `Concat` will just concatenate the results. You could use `OrderBy` but that is inefficient. We're basically trying to write a Merge Concatenation here

Comment: I get 1,2,2,3,4,5,5,0,0 from your code. Looks like the issue is it doesn't take into account one array is bigger than the other

Comment: Are the input arrays guaranteed to be correctly sorted? If not, you are doomed to fail.

Comment: I would guess that OP not allowed to use `Sort` or LINQ's `OrderBy`

Comment: i need to find a simple way to solve it because its for homework, just simple methods

Comment: @Fabio no one should be allowed to use any sort to merge two **sorted** arrays. Whether it is homework or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry I don't see where OP mentioned about arrays being already sorted

Comment: `this is the output` What output do you _want_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we need is `for` loop:

```
static void Merge(int[] left, int[] right) 
  for (int indexLeft = 0, indexRight = 0; 
       indexLeft < left.Length || indexRight < right.Length;) 
    if (indexRight >= right.Length || 
       (indexLeft < left.Length && left[indexLeft] <= right[indexRight])) 
      Console.WriteLine(left[indexLeft++]);
    else
      Console.WriteLine(right[indexRight++]);
}
```

we move by *both* `left` and `right` arrays (`indexLeft`, `indexRight`) and we print item from `left` array if and only if

1. We exhausted `right` array: `indexRight >= right.Length`.
2. If we have items in both `left` and `right` arrays and `left[indexLeft] <= right[indexRight]`

otherwise we print `right` array item.

**Edit:** If you want to return *merged array* (`result`):

```
static int[] Merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
  int[] result = new int[left.Length + right.Length];
  int index = 0;

  for (int indexLeft = 0, indexRight = 0; 
       indexLeft < left.Length || indexRight < right.Length;) 
    if (indexRight >= right.Length || 
       (indexLeft < left.Length && left[indexLeft] <= right[indexRight])) 
      result[index++] = left[indexLeft++];
    else
      result[index++] = right[indexRight++];

  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need merge two arrays into one array sorted

Comment: @ohad: a small modification will return merged array; see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely different approach to the problem.  It works with any kind of collection of any type that implements `IComparable<T>` (i.e., any `IEnumerable<T> where T: IComparable<T>`.

It uses simple enumeration, no indexes.  It does require that the inputs are pre-sorted.  I didn't test to see what happens if that pre-condition is false (nor do I check the pre-condition (since you don't want to sort)).

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second) where T : IComparable<T>
 {
     //assumption: both first and second are already sorted.
     var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator();
     var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator();
     var result = new List<T>();
     if (!firstEnumerator.MoveNext())
     {
         //nothing in first collection, so...
         return second;
     }

     if (!secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
     {
         //nothing in second collection, so...
         return first;
     }

     var firstComplete = false;
     var secondComplete = false;

     while (true)
     {
         if (firstComplete && secondComplete)
         {
             break;
         }
         if (secondComplete || (!firstComplete && firstEnumerator.Current.CompareTo(secondEnumerator.Current) < 0))
         {
             result.Add(firstEnumerator.Current);
             if (!firstEnumerator.MoveNext())
             {
                 firstComplete = true;
             }
         }
         else if (!secondComplete)
         {
             result.Add(secondEnumerator.Current);
             if (!secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
             {
                 secondComplete = true;
             }
         }
     }

     return result;
 }
```

Here's some test code:

```
var first = new[] {1, 4, 300, 2000};
var second = new[] {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 2500};
var result = Merge(first, second);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I've tried reversing the first and second assignments, and a few other combinations.  The output from that looks like:

```
1
2
4
4
6
8
10
12
14
300
2000
2500
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was homework.  If I had known, I would have given you "here's how you could do it" (without any code) rather than showing you a solution.  You could probably take the logic in the code above, and reimplement it with arrays and indexes.  That would be a good homework exercise (write a method for determining if you've reached the end of an array if you want).  Consider doing this for an array of `T`, not just an array of `int` though

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach it might be more simple to read:

```cs
private static int[] Merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] c = new int[a.Length + b.Length];
    int iA = 0, iB = 0, iC = 0; 
    while (iC < c.Length) 
    {
        c[iC++] = iA < a.Length
            ? iB < b.Length 
                ? a[iA] < b[iB] 
                    ? a[iA++] 
                    : b[iB++]
                : a[iA++]
            : iB < b.Length 
                ? b[iB++] 
                : throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    return c;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] b = { 2, 5, 8, 11 };
    int[] c = Merge(a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you and I have a different definition of _simple to read_; an expression with 4 terneraries in it!

Answer (score -1):

`Array` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can use the extension methods of IEnumerable.
Here is an example:

```
int[] array_1 = { 1, 3, 6 };
int[] array_2 = { 2, 5 };
int[] array_3 = array_1.Concat(array_2).OrderBy(nr => nr).ToArray();  
  
// array_3: { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 }
```

Comment: thanks but this is for homework and im not allowed to use this method

Comment: Then, this is more an algorithmic/logic question rather than a C# one.

Comment: This is a sub-optimal way to merge two sorted arrays. While it is indeed possible to do worse (i.e. concat + bubble sort for O(n^2) ), there is no good reason to go for O(n log n) solution where O(n) is needed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I wasn't told arrays could contain tens/hundreds of records :D So it all depends on the scenario